# Sonoma using xcode 14.3.1 error CompileStoryboard failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode

```
CompileStoryboard /Volumes/DATA/ADVN-GIT/TRACK-CLIENT/TRACK-IOS/TrackCustomer/TrackCustomer/Storyboards/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard (in target 'TrackCustomer' from project 'TrackCustomer')
    cd /Volumes/DATA/ADVN-GIT/TRACK-CLIENT/TRACK-IOS/TrackCustomer
    /Applications/Xcode14.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module TrackCustomer --output-partial-info-plist /Users/sangnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackCustomer-cwqpmlkqnbvpnegetefohaemsnhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TrackCustomer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TrackCustomer.build/Base.lproj/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 14.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/sangnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackCustomer-cwqpmlkqnbvpnegetefohaemsnhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TrackCustomer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TrackCustomer.build/Base.lproj /Volumes/DATA/ADVN-GIT/TRACK-CLIENT/TRACK-IOS/TrackCustomer/TrackCustomer/Storyboards/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard

2023-11-22 17:06:08.887 IBAgent-iOS[48936:823068] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFUI-Regular", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].
2023-11-22 17:06:08.887 IBAgent-iOS[48936:823068] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
2023-11-22 17:06:08.887 IBAgent-iOS[48936:823068] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFUI-Semibold", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].
2023-11-22 17:06:08.887 IBAgent-iOS[48936:823068] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFUI-RegularItalic", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].
2023-11-22 17:06:09.279 ibtoold[48862:821665] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-21701/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/Archiving/Conformance/IBSystemClassArchiving.m:41
Details:  Assertion failed: [self methodForSelector:@selector(encodeWithCoder:)] == [class instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(encodeWithCoder:)]
Function: void IBAssertEncodeWithCoderFromClass(__strong id, __unsafe_unretained Class)
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x600000e24980>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _DVTAssertionWarningHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4   -[NSLocale(IBDocumentArchiving) unarchiveWithDocumentUnarchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5   __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11   -[IBUIDatePicker(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 12   __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16   __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21   -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibArchiveSubviews:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22   -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23   -[IBUIView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 24   __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 27   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 28   __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 33   -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibArchiveSubviews:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34   -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35   -[IBUIView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 36   __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 37   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 38   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 39   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 41   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 42   -[IBUIViewController(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 43   __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 44   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 45   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 46   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 47   __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 48   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 49   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 50   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 51   __47-[IBStoryboardDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 52   __69-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:forOptionalKey:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 53   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 54   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 55   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:forOptionalKey:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 56   __47-[IBStoryboardDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 57   __69-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:forOptionalKey:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 58   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 59   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 60   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:forOptionalKey:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 61   -[IBStoryboardDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 62   -[IBDocument archiveAndVerifyArchivingOfTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 63   -[IBDocument archivePlatformIndependentDataWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 64   -[IBStoryboardDocument archivePlatformIndependentDataWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 65   -[IBDocument archiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 66   __100-[IBDocumentArchiver elementRepresentationOfArchivableDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 67   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithArchiveToken:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 68   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 69   -[IBDocumentArchiver elementRepresentationOfArchivableDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 70   -[IBDocumentArchiver dataRepresentationOfArchivableDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 71   -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 72   -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 73   -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 74   -[IBDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 75   -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] (in AppKit)
 76   -[IDEEditorDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOpeCommand CompileStoryboard failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I just upgraded macos ventura to sonoma, running xcode 15.0.1 had an error so I downloaded xcode 14.3.1. Previously, xcode 14.3.1 ran without any problems, but when I installed it on sonoma, the application build had an error, like the new macos was missing the fonts or there was some problem with the fonts still not being built even though I searched all over the internet.
Hope you can support, Thanks

Comment: Same issue. Have any help?